# How to serialise access to a single device from multiple async tasks?

Tags: c#, async-await, .net-6.0, excel-dna

I have **single** external resource - named pipe. I need to be able to do the following:

- multiple async tasks can be spawn nearly simultaneously (by EXCEL-DNA function, ran in many cells)
- tasks will try to aquire access to the pipe (there can be only one pipe per app) in arbitrary manner
- the winning task will send request and wait for the response, then release the pipe to next waiting task
- a task waiting for too long should continue after timeout (return "#err" value)
- *I am not yet sure whether tasks will be fired from different threads (I am new to excel-dna)*

I can't quite figure out an elegant way to do it (one thing comes to mind - a r/w lock with timeout).

Is there a pure async solution for such problem?

Comment: Do the tasks need to write directly to the pipe?  Another option might be for them to add their output to a thread-safe queue of some kind, and have a separate thread that processes the queue and always owns the pipe.  I don't know whether there are any lock-free thread-safe queue types in net-60 so that might still be locking.

Comment: Ha.. I wish you told me how they would get response back from that queue.. I wouldn't ask if I knew. It's no problem to add requests from tasks to a concurrent queue and process them one by one in a single worker thread.. But! How will it find the corresponding task and "post" back the response?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you can use a queue for this, just like Dave suggests in the comments.

With the help of a [`TaskCompletionSource<TResult>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskcompletionsource-1), you can create your own tasks that you can complete with our own logic.

The following is a simple incomplete example (not tested and just typed here) of how you can implement something like this:

```cs
public class PipeAccess
{
  private readonly ConcurrentQueue<ScheduledTask> _queue

  public Task<string> GetResult(string input) {
    var schedule = new ScheduledTask(input);
    _queue.Enqueue(schedule);
    return schedule.Completion.Task;
  }

  private sealed class ScheduledTask
  {
    private CancellationTokenSource _timeout;
    private IDisposable _timeoutRegistration;

    public ScheduleTask(string input)
    {
      Input = input;
      Completion = new TaskCompletionSource<string>(TaskCreationOptions.RunContinuationsAsynchronously);
      _timeout = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
      _timeoutRegistration = _timeout.Token.Register(() => Completion.TrySetCancelled());
    }

    public string Input { get; }

    public TaskCompletionSource<string> Completion { get; }

    public bool StartProcessing()
    {
      _timeoutRegistration.Dispose();
      _timeout.Dispose();
      return !Completion.Task.IsCancelled;
    }
  }
}
```

In this example I haven't included code how you read the next task from the queue but you start with calling `StartProcessing()` so you stop the timeout. If this returns a `false`, then this task is already timed out and you can just go to the next item in the queue. Otherwise you do your thing with the pipe, and the result you can set to the [`Completion.TrySetResult()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskcompletionsource-1.trysetresult), any errors that occured can be set to [`Completion.TrySetException()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskcompletionsource-1.trysetexception).

I have included the [`TaskCreationOptions.RunContinuationsAsynchronously`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskcreationoptions) because otherwise the code that is awaiting the `PipeAccess.GetResult()` will continue on this thread, making your `PipeAccess` wait until that code is done before it can continue to the next queued task (and increasing the likelyhood of a timeout).

Comment: What's the point of the queue if only one task is ever active?

Comment: This code is in response to you comment https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77069646/how-to-serialise-access-to-a-single-device-from-multiple-async-tasks/77845610?noredirect=1#comment135865657_77069646. Here I show how you can find the corresponding task and 'post' back the response (with the `TaskCompletionSource`). You said that you already know how to add tasks to a concurrent queue and process them one by one in a single worker thread.

Comment: In case I misread your question, this is in response to your orignal bullet points:
- multiple async tasks can be spawn ... => Here you condense them into a single queue/thread
- tasks will try to aquire access ... => It's easier if there is only a single thread that does this
- the winning task will send ... => This is done with the `TaskCompletionSource`
- a task waiting for too long should ... => This is done with the help of the `CancellationTokenSource`
- I am not yet sure whether tasks ... => I can't help you with this, but with this code it doesn't matter